# Как обрезать div по тексту?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно, чтобы `div` был обрезан по тексту (точнее его границы). По вертикали все хорошо обрезается, а вот по горизонтали растягивается на всю страницу. Если какой-то элемент для этого подходит лучше чем `div`, тогда подскажите, пожалуйста, какой.

Ниже прикрепил картинку, чтобы было понятней. Красным обозначены границы `div`, которые сейчас. А зеленым - те, которые мне нужны.

Повторюсь. Если есть какой-то элемент, который подойдет для этого лучше, чем `div`, то подскажите, какой, пожалуйста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Блочные элементы, каким является `<div>`, имеют ширину по умолчанию 100%. Поэтому нужно изменить свойство `display`:

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid #090;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>ТЕКСТ</div>
```

... или задать ширину по содержимому:

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid #090;
  width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<div>ТЕКСТ</div>
```